# How to call filepath for files listed in a .properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, filepath

I have a .properties file that is under a source folder I made called `res` (using Eclipse Mars 2). I have two other folders in there called `messages` and `schemas`.

I need help in giving a filepath so it works locally and on a server (e.g. JBoss) after making the project into a `.war` file. This is my .properties file:

```
# Credentials
user=flow
password=flow

# Path to schema for validation
schemaPath=schemas/Schema1.xsd

# Path to where you want to keep incoming and outgoing messages
messagePath=messages/
```

The above properties file will only work if I provide the full path to the two different `*Path` properties (above is not full path). However, I can't do that because it needs to work on the application server and on different operating systems.

In my code, I save the filepaths to Strings and use those Strings to specify where to write or read. How can I make it so it works after deploying to the server using a `.war` file?

I am using a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Mars 2.

**EDIT**: Since the properties is user configurable, they might give a full path. It should work whether the path is short as shown or the full path.

Comment: If your application is deployed as a WAR, how can the values for those properties be relative paths? They can't (shouldn't) add files into the WAR and your application can't write to the WAR. What would it mean for the values of those paths to be relative as you've shown?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking me. I wanted to specify where those directories will be located in the project since they can be changed by another developer. They can either be inside the project folder structure or outside of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the `properties` file is part of the `classpath`, that is usually including it in `classes/` directory.

Mark the folder with `properties` file as `Source Folder` in your eclipse. If it is in a package, then use that package name in your path while loading the file.

For example, if the file is in `config/data.properties`, then load the file by `.getResource("config/data.properties");`

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I can read the `properties` file just fine. I can't get the filepaths inside the `properties` file to work unless I give it a fully qualified path (e.g. `C:/Users/flow/Desktop/Project/....`). Since the program will be used on Linux and Windows, I can't give it a path like that.